# DataValidation, strange error

Tags: excel, excel-2010

I am trying to validate an Excel column to have only values containing a value with `length > 1` and ending with "d".
My attempt was the following formula:

```
=AND(LEN(INDIRECT(ADDRESS(ROW(),COLUMN())))>1,RIGHT(INDIRECT(ADDRESS(ROW(),COLUMN())),1) = "d")
```

Excel says that the formula contains errors. 
The strange thing is that the first part itself works correct. But when i put it into an AND i get the error. Also when i replace the inderect reference with an absolut one it will work:

```
=LEN(INDIRECT(ADDRESS(ROW(),COLUMN())))>1 => works

=AND(LEN(F4)>1, TRUE) => works

=AND(LEN(INDIRECT(ADDRESS(ROW(),COLUMN())))>1, TRUE) => fails
```

Why is this? Is there another way or a workaround to do this?

Thanks in advance, Marco

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure why you need this to be so complicated. In data/validation Custom formula for the top cell in the column, put something like `=AND(LEN(H1)>1,RIGHT(H1,1)="d")`  (for col H, for example). Then Copy that cell, and Paste Special/Validation for the rest of the cells in the column.  Any good?

Comment: It seems that it works when i mark the whole range and use the first cell as reference in the formula, Excel updates the formula for each cell to reference itself. Say you select D7:D100 then just use D7 to have a reference to the current cell.